# Getting values from another column, from different row but from same table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.4.

I have valves on a water pipeline that are in either 'on' or 'off' ('tilstand' - 'on' / 'off') condition.
In another column, there is the valve, that is physically placed before the valve in the column "no".
I manually fill in column "v_hl_ventil-1" but want column "tilstand-1" to automatically retrieve data from column "tilstand" for the corresponding “nr” and change automatically, depending on condition in “tilstand”.

[image]

Comment: Add your layer twice to your project with different name and create a join between these two layers. After the join you can update the fields of the base layer with the fields of the joined layer. Use the field calculator for update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Field Calculator to update `tilstand-1` field by:

```
attribute(get_feature('bernd', 'nr', "v_hl_ventil-1"), 'tilstand')
```

- Please replace `'bernd'` by the real layer name you are working on.
- Pay attention to single / double quotation marks.

[image]

If you are looking to update on-the-fly, there are QAs about setting `virtual field` and/or `Default value`. Anyway, hope the above expression gives you a good start.